# Kafka Streams API: Avoid additional stateStore in KTable.mapValues

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ktable

Currently we use the following in our Kafka Streams application:

```
streamsBuilder.table(inputTopic)
              .join(...)
              .mapValues(valueMapper) // <-- this causes another state store
              .groupBy(...)
              .aggregate(...)
              .mapValues(...)

[...]
              .toStream()
              .to(outputTopic)
```

and I just realized, that the mapValues after the join creates an additional state store.

If the calculation in valueMapper is somehow trivial (e.g. remove a field in an object etc), would it not be better to avoid the additional statestore?
Do I need to convert to a KStream and use KStream.mapValues to avoid a stateStore, i.e.

```
streamsBuilder.table(inputTopic)
              .join(...)
              .toStream
              .mapValues(valueMapper) // <-- no more additional statestore
              .groupBy(...)
              .aggregate(...)
              .mapValues(...)

[...]
              .toStream()
              .to(outputTopic)
```

**or is there a better alternative to apply additonal mapping after a join?**

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to use a mapValues after a join step? If it is possible to handle that logic in the ValueJoiner of the join.

```
streamsBuilder.table(inputTopic)
              .join( anotherTable, (a ,b) ->  c )  <--- Here you can perform any mapping process
              .toStream
              .groupBy(...)
              .aggregate(...)
              .mapValues(...)

[...]
              .toStream()
              .to(outputTopic)
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwer and the suggestion to perform the mapping in the ValueJoiner. It is probably the right and most lightwight approach. IMHO, it is counterintuitive to do this in the Kafka DSL join function.Do I understand correctly that with every method call on a KTable a new statestore is created which holds the results?

Comment: Yes you are right,  according the documentation each KTable function that returns a  KTable   is creating a new KTable, this is because the Kafka Streams API needs to know what is the latest status for a given  Key.    KTable filteredTable = streamsBuilder.table().filter(  ....);
filteredTable.toStream()
filteredTable.groupBy().  // Kaka needs to know what is the status of the filtered table.  Even check the description of each method always says crete a new KTable https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html